# i want to separate data frame based on marks and download it then

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my data frame:

```
     Name  Age    Stream  Percentage
0      A   21      Math          88
1      B   19  Commerce          92
2      C   20      Arts          95
3      D   18   Biology          70
0      E   21      Math          88
1      F   19  Commerce          92
2      G   20      Arts          95
3      H   18   Biology          70
```

I want to download different excel file for each subject in one loop so basically, I should get 4 excel files for each subject

i tried this but didn't work:

```
n=0
for subjects in df.stream:
  df.to_excel("sub"+ str(n)+".xlsx") 
  n+=1
```

Answer (score 4):

I think `groupby` is helpful here. and you can use `enumerate` to keep track of the index.

```
for i, (group, group_df) in enumerate(df.groupby('stream')):
    group_df.to_excel('sub{}.xlsx'.format(i))
    # Alternatively, to name the file based on the stream...
    group_df.to_excel('sub{}.xlsx'.format(group))
```

`group` is going to be the name of the stream.

`group_df` is going to be a sub-dataframe containing all the data in that group.